# Count new user since last user visit

Tags: django

I need create function with count of new users since last user visit. How can I do this using cookies?

my try:

**views:**

```
...
users = User.objects.all().count()
response = HttpResponse()
if not request.COOKIES.get('new_users'):
    response.set_cookie('new_users', 0)
    n = request.COOKIES.get('new_users')
else:
    old = request.COOKIES.get('new_users')
    new  = int(users) - int(old)
    if new >=1:
        response.set_cookie('new_users', new)
        n = request.COOKIES.get('new_users')
return render_to_response('main.html', {'n': n}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but still there are some odd values (in `n`). Should I create this function in my index view or where? What is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

Best place would be to create a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) function to handle this logic.

Take into account that a middleware function will be executed for each request, so make your function very efficient (I didn't take much look of your implementation)